# How to get common value in Object Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const data =  {
"games": [
    {
        "id": "828de9122149499183df39c6ae2dd3ab",
        "developer_id": "885911",
        "game_name": "Minecraft",
        "first_release": "2011-18-11",
        "website": "https://www.minecraft.net/en-us"
    },
    {
        "id": "61ee6f196c58afc9c1f78831",
        "developer_id": "810637",
        "game_name": "Fortnite",
        "first_release": "2017-21-07",
        "website": "https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/home"
    },
],

"developers": [
    {
        "id": "885911",
        "name": "Mojang Studios",
        "country": "US",
        "website": "http://www.mojang.com",
    },
    {
        "id": "750245",
        "name": "God of War",
        "country": "SE",
        "website": "https://sms.playstation.com",
    },
] };
```

I have json data like this. I want to display data like if developer_id = 885911(from games array) then print id(from developers array) and if the both are same then I want to print the name.(Mojang studios) and so on like games website etc. How can I do that?

Comment: _"I have json data like this."_ - There's no [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question

Comment: What is the expected output/result? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I want to check developer_id (from games array) and id (from developers array) are same then I want to print the name of developer. (In this case Mojang Studios)

Comment: That's already (1:1) in your question... _"I want to print..."_ - Where? How? Where is the `developer_id` coming from? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In console or in plane JS. I've tried map method but it didn't work for me.  FYI developer_id and developers ID are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This sample code will show you the developer of each game, if it's found:

```js
const data =  {
"games": [
    {
        "id": "828de9122149499183df39c6ae2dd3ab",
        "developer_id": "885911",
        "game_name": "Minecraft",
        "first_release": "2011-18-11",
        "website": "https://www.minecraft.net/en-us"
    },
    {
        "id": "61ee6f196c58afc9c1f78831",
        "developer_id": "810637",
        "game_name": "Fortnite",
        "first_release": "2017-21-07",
        "website": "https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/home"
    },
],

"developers": [
    {
        "id": "885911",
        "name": "Mojang Studios",
        "country": "US",
        "website": "http://www.mojang.com",
    },
    {
        "id": "750245",
        "name": "God of War",
        "country": "SE",
        "website": "https://sms.playstation.com",
    },
] };

const gameDevelopers = data.games.map(g => ({
  game: g.game_name, 
  developer: data.developers.find(d => d.id === g.developer_id)?.name || "No matching developer found"
}));

console.log(gameDevelopers)
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you exactly need? i don't understand . But you can get value Mojang Studios

```
  console.log(data.developers[0].name)
```

If you need  all developer id then you can use

```
  console.log(data.developers.map(data=>{
    console.log(data.id)
   }))
```

If you need the id where name is Mojang Studios

```
   console.log(data.developers.map(data=>{
    if(data.name == "Mojang Studios"){
       console.log(data.id)
    }
    }))
```

Comment: Nope. check my older comments for more detail.

Comment: I want to check developer_id (from games array) and id (from developers array) are same then I want to print the name of developer. (In this case Mojang Studios) from developers array.

Comment: Thanks but that's not I was looking for. I have tons of data in json object.

Comment: What do you exactly  need ?